# Javascript ES6 Array Method for comparing current array value to next

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient ES6 way to find a value in an array that is greater than the value at the current index, but less than the value at index+1. If found, I want to return the lower bound, and if not found I assume "Winter" in my example. After trying map, findIndex, filter, reduce, and some I have had varying levels of success. It's been quite the learning experience! The problem with the array methods is that index+1 throws an exception at the last comparison since index+1 is out  of bounds. Here is the array:

```
var sea27 = [
    {name: 'Spring', date: 1553140800000},
    {name: 'Summer', date: 1561089600000},
    {name: 'Autumn', date: 1569211200000},
    {name: 'Winter', date: 1576904400000}
];
```

and here is my attempt using Array.some which I think is the appropriate method since it returns true/false and the index. However since Array.reduce start at index 1, perhaps that is the best way, but I was not able to make the accumulator work. Also chaining methods might help, but it's beyond my level of understanding.

```
p = new Date("7/31/2019").getTime();
console.log(pp)
ww = sea27.some(function (e, idx, a) {return pp > a[idx].date && pp < ~a[idx+1].date  && ~(i = idx);});
console.log( "array some try", ww, i, (ww)?sea27[i].name:"Winter");
// "Summer"
// new Date("12/31/2019").getTime(); Exception.
```

My question, is there a better way/method?, and if array some is the right array method, how do I stop when index+1 is above length? The following is not working either.

```
ww = sea27.some(function (e, idx, a) {console.log(a.length);return pp > a[idx].date && pp < a[(idx+1 < a.length-1)? idx+1 : a.length].date  && ~(i = idx);});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _Array.some which I think is the appropriate method since it returns true/false and the index_ => [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) just returns `true` or `false`, nothing more. Maybe you can try `Array.find()` or `Array.findIndex()`...

Comment: Array.some can return the index as in my example. findIndex() has the same problem when index+1 is out of bounds.

Comment: You lost me at `~a[idx+1].date  && ~(i = idx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var sea27 = [
    {name: 'Spring', date: 1553140800000},
    {name: 'Summer', date: 1561089600000},
    {name: 'Autumn', date: 1569211200000},
    {name: 'Winter', date: 1576904400000}
];
p = new Date("7/31/2019").getTime();


var ele = sea27.find(function(ele, idx, arr) {
    if (idx == arr.length - 1 && p >= ele.date) {
        return true;
    }
    if (idx == 0 && p <= arr[idx+1].date) {
        return true;
    }
    if (p >= ele.date && p <= arr[idx+1].date) {
        return true
    }
});

console.log(ele);
```

Comment: This one works if 1 is subtracted from arr.length, ie: `if (idx == arr.length-1) {`, I was hoping for an arrow function 1 liner so I favor and @Bergi solution below, however it gives an undefined for dates under the first array date value, ie " 1/1/2019'. I'll mark this one as the answer if I don't get any other ideas. Thank you.

Comment: @Bob Tha's right. Snippet updated. You may always reduce to an one line arrow function. In any case, consider the readability and the numbers of constraints you want. Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`find` should work just fine. Yes, you need an extra condition to check for the end of the array, in which case you'd assume that your value is smaller than the non-existing next one.

```
const value = …; // to compare against
const result = array.find((val, i) =>
    val.date <= value && (i+1 == array.length || value < array[i+1].date)
);
```

This will return the last array element when the `value` is larger than the last element, and will return `undefined` when the `value` is smaller than the first element. Of course, given your array is ordered, this could be optimised by a binary search.